# How to show jsp content in ExtJs window?

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

I have a jsp with ExtJs application. I click a button new Ext.Window appers . In this window i want to show forms from another jsp. Its mean that i want:
1 Send parametrs to jsp.
2 Fill a forms according to these parameters.
3 Show froms in window.
4 After  send parametrs to first jsp.

Another way its send a parameters in second jsp and create window and forms in this jsp and show it.

Which way is more correct and how to realize it?

Comment: Do you need to open a new browser window? Or it is just a kind of pop up form? I don't think that JSP is needed in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second way might be easier.  The Ext Window (or it's parent Panel) component has [contentEl](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-contentEl) property that can be specified. What this does is load the html of the element into the Panel component as html property. So you can take an existing JSP with all of its rendered html on the server side and show it as is inside a Window panel.

The first way might be achieved through a [component loader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-loader) . What this does is lets you load content of a remote page (JSP in your case) into your Ext component. I have not used this so I am not sure what limitations you might face with this. There are however some interesting possibilities described in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader